# Neo4J odd behavior on nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, neo4j

Im trying to create a simple upsert/merge in neo4j with the nodejs driver.

I send the same params over and over again and a new node with the same originId is created, what am I doing wrong?

I expect that only one node with same originId will be in the database...

```
const query = `MERGE (n:item {originId:$originId})
                  ON MATCH  SET
                        n.originId=$originId
                  ON CREATE
                     SET
                        n.originId=$originId,
                        n.searchTerm=$searchTerm,
                        n.subSearchTerm=$subSearchTerm,
                        n.licenseType=$licenseType,
                        n.location=$location
                  RETURN n
`;

        const res = await this.noe4jDriver.executeQuery(query, {
            originId: String(payload.data.id),
            searchTerm: payload.data.searchTerm,
            subSearchTerm: payload.data.subSearchTerm,
            licenseType: payload.data.licenseType,
            location: payload.data.location,
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried the same query directly on neo4j browser, works fine, can you check what is the query that is being fired to neo4j from the application?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor thanks, in the GUI it works, but in nodejs it doesnt. The query that is being fired out is the same as I wrote.

Comment: Are you using this driver? https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver

Comment: @CharchitKapoor yes I am, the odd thing, I have created a cleaned version of my app and I cant reproduce that...

Comment: Wow, that's strange and interesting

Comment: How is your "cleaned" version different? Also, although it should not cause the behavior you observed, there is never a need to `SET n.originId=$originId` after your `MERGE`, since the desired `originId` value is guaranteed to be set already. So, your `ON MATCH SET ...` is not needed, and your `ON CREATE SET ...` should be modified.

Comment: Also, do you ever create `item` nodes in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `MERGE` can be made concurrently, that can cause duplicate nodes unless you have created a uniqueness constraint beforehand, like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (i:item) REQUIRE i.originId IS UNIQUE;
```

To quote from the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) documentation:

> Under concurrent updates, `MERGE` only guarantees the existence of the
> `MERGE` pattern, but not uniqueness. To guarantee uniqueness of nodes
> with certain properties, a [property uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) should be
> used. See [Using property uniqueness constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-using-unique-constraints) with `MERGE`.